# How to close active datareader c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to select values out of a mySQL database. All good and well but the first time i ran the code I forgot to close the datareader. Now every time I run my updated code, it errors, stating there is already an active datareader for that connection that must be closed first.   I have tried ending the SQL instance as well as restarting my PC, but the error remains. How do I close this datareader

Below is the updated code

```
public static int getProductIDbyName(string productName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection.State.ToString()!="Open")
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            string query = "SELECT * FROM  `tblproduct` WHERE  `ProductName` =  '"+productName+"'";
            if (connection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            {
                int result = 0;
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            result = Convert.ToInt16(dataReader["ID"].ToString());
                        }

                        dataReader.Close();
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
                MySqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [`reader.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close(v=vs.110).aspx)? It might be helpful if you showed the data reader code...

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Re the edit: are you saying that this *one single* piece of code is the only code that creates a reader, and causes this? is there no other code that might be operating on `connection`, perhaps? (I strongly suspect that there is)

Comment: Additional thought: **never, ever** concatenate input into SQL; you should *use parameters*. I wrote a treatise on this earlier today, using "Dapper" as the example: http://blog.marcgravell.com/2017/12/dapper-prepared-statements-and-car-tyres.html - and: you don't need to use `ToString()` to compare enum values - just: *compare it to an enum value*

Comment: I think there might be. Is there a way to allow multiple readers to function through the same connection?

Comment: multiple readers on a single connection is not universally supported, and often needs to be enabled; on SQL Server, for example, you need to explicitly add `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to the connection string to turn this feature on. I have no idea whether MySql has a similar feature, but it wouldn't surprise me *at all* if it didn't. You aren't usually *meant* to do that. Note: the problem here is having multiple *concurrent* readers - you can have as many *successive* readers *as you like*.

Comment: You were right, I did have an additional reader going off on that at the same time.

Comment: I just have to say: with dapper, this entire thing would be `public static int getProductIDbyName(string productName) => connection.QuerySingleOrDefault<int>("SELECT * FROM  \`tblproduct\` WHERE  \`ProductName\` = @productName", new { productName });` - it would literally do everything you show, including connection lifetime handling, parameterization and data consumption

Comment: Thanks I will look into this dapper you speak of XD

Comment: @HeinBotha side note: it looks like you have a `static MySqlConnection connection` - that is usually a terrible idea; you might get away with it if this is a client application, but if this is a web-server or a WCF server or similar: you will fail as soon as you scale above a single user

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ExecuteReader` on a `DbCommand`, the reader that you get *is disposable* - i.e. it implements `IDisposable`. You should consume it with a `using` block. Then: when your code leaves the block, everything will happen automatically:

```
using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    // ... consume the data
}
```

Alternatively, use a tool like "Dapper" (free, etc) that will do this correctly for you, and make it easier to write ADO.NET.

Comment: Yes this is how I've updated my code, but this doesn't solve the problem, it just prevents it from happening again. The problem is that when it tries to create a new datareader, it breaks because there is a preexisting one.

Comment: @HeinBotha as long as you do this *in every place where you use readers*, it should work fine. Are you sure you aren't doing something involving nested readers? i.e. while you're reading one set of data, you're starting a command to do something else? If not: code would *really help*

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I'm using.